# Mozilla Firefox lost button

Tags: firefox

The last upgrading from Mozilla Firefox has a lost button.

When we go to "Preferences", then to "Privacy and Security", then to "Clean History", if we want to clean all... We don't have any button to do that!

What's happened with that button?

How can we clean the navigator history?

NEW DATA:

I discovered that this problem is ONLY present with screen monitors that have less than 1024 pixels of height!

I discovered it, because the old monitor of one of my desktp PC died. So, I had to use another monitor with 1280x1024 pixels of resolution and... Now I can see the lost button!

So... The issue is about... How to get Firefox shows those buttons with less than 1024 pixels height resolution?

These are the images to clear the issue:

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second image, the [Clear All] button doesn't appear.

Comment: On my install it's still there. It's called "CleaR history", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last upgrading from Mozilla Firefox, solved it!!!

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut still present in Firefox 64 is to press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> at the same time to bring up the *Clear Recent History* window.

Alternatively, open *Preferences > Privacy & Security > History*.

Carefully select what you want to clear by ticking or unticking the relevant boxes. Then, click on the dropdown next to *Time range to clear* and choose *Everything*:

[image: Clear Recent History]

Comment: In my system the [CONTROL]+[SHIFT]+[DELETE] combination gives me a session restart! Nothing related with Firefox!

Comment: In that case, just follow the method you use to reach the *Preferences > Privacy > History* section. Do you then not see the image above?

Comment: Please! See the new data information